# Validate HTML entities in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a small JavaScript validation script that validates inputs based on Regex. I want to allow certain characters that are not exactly common (not sure if they're UTF8). For example I want to allow the following character `’`, which looks like a single quote, but isn't.

I got the HTML code for this which is `&#8217;`, but I'm not sure how to put this into the Regex.

I've tried just inputting `[&#8217]*` but it doesn't validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
/[\u2019]/
```

It uses the actual character rather than the html entity. 2019 is hex for 8217<sub>10</sub>

http://jsfiddle.net/eV2ek/

Comment: Right on! Worked perfectly :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you properly tag encoding of your JavaScript (or its holding page if it is inline) either through `charset` attribute or `Content-Type` header, you can just use any character that doesn't have special meaning in regexp just by typing it there literally:

```
/’/
```

Comment: I've thought of that, but the problem is that if I open it with an editor/IDE that doesn't support "special" characters (like I'm *guessing* `nano`), this character might be lost/replaced.

Comment: Yes, using character code is most bulletproof, but I find it hard to believe that any actively updated editor (and `nano`, as I remember, is) doesn't support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of `&#8217;` or `&#x2019;` in regex in most of environments is

```
\u2019
```

however in Perl and PCRE `\u` is not supported , but `\x` syntax instead

```
\x2019
```

as `2019` is hex of decimal `8217`.

Regarding unicode with regex in Javascript read: [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)